# Are RabbitMQ concepts like Exchange or Queue still valid when using the MQTT protocol?

Tags: websocket, rabbitmq, mqtt, publish-subscribe, amqp

RabbitMQ has a [plugin](https://www.rabbitmq.com/web-mqtt.html) that exposes RabbitMQ to browsers through websockets using the MQTT protocol.

I've used RabbitMQ in the past and I am familiar with its Exchange, Queue and routing concepts.

However I used it with the AMQP protocol.
Do I have to re-learn a new concepts if I use this plugin or are queue, exchange and routing concepts protocol agnostic in RabbitMQ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

MQTT doesn't have the concept of queues or exchanges... just a hierarchical topic structure.  The plugin publishes MQTT messages onto a topic exchange (`amq.topic` by default), and then Rabbit consumers read the messages from queues that are bound to the exchange.  Note that the plugin will convert between MQTT's `/` topic separator with Rabbit's `.` separator.

Another option to consider (full discloure, I work for them): [Solace PubSub+ message broker](https://solace.com/) supports MQTT *natively* without any plugins (both TCP and WebSockets connections), as well as AMQP 1.0 natively.  Solace also has a REST messaging interface (e.g. POST REST, consume as WebSockets message), as well as a bunch of "enterprise" APIs (e.g. send MQTT message, consume using JMS topic), so my browser and back-end server app exchange messages directly.  And it's free, with full HA and DR built in.  Check it at `dev.solace.com`.